# Symfony form multiple select entities with many relationships

Tags: php, symfony, entity, formbuilder

Sorry in advance for the quality of my English

I would create a form to create a Employee. Employee and Team are connected with the ManytoOne bidirectional Relation, Team and Division are connected with the ManytoOne bidirectional Relation, and Division and Center are connected with the manytoOne bidirectional Relation. In my form I want to be able to filter the list of Teams with Javascript, according to the choice made on a first select on Center then Division to reduce the list of Teams.

Here is my code :

EmployeeType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('birthDate',          DateType::class)
        ->add('firstName',          TextType::class)
        ->add('name',               TextType::class)
        ->add('isActive',           CheckboxType::class, array('required' => false))
        ->add('employeePicture',    EmployeePictureType::class)
        ->add('team',               TeamType::class)
        ->add('save',               SubmitType::class);
}
```

TeamType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('shortName',EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'RTELiveWorkingBundle:Team',
            'choice_label'  => 'shortName',
            'placeholder'   => 'Choisir une équipe'
        ))
        ->add('divsion', DivisionType::class);
}
```

DivisionType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('shortName',EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'RTELiveWorkingBundle:Division',
            'choice_label'  => 'shortName',
            'placeholder'   => 'Choisir un GMR'
        ))
        ->add('center', CenterType::class);
}
```

And CenterType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('shortName',EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'RTELiveWorkingBundle:Center',
            'choice_label'  => 'shortName',
            'placeholder'   => 'Choisir un centre'
        ));
}
```

My controller :

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {

    $employee = new Employee();

    $form = $this->createForm(EmployeeType::class, $employee);

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($employee);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('rte_live_working_employee_view', array('id' => $employee->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('RTELiveWorkingBundle:Employee:add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

My forms :

[image]

I have the error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Method
>   RTE\LiveWorkingBundle\Entity\Team::__toString() must return a string
>   value

But I have to implement `__toString()` in my entity :

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getShortName();
}
```

have you got an idea ?

Comment: I believe method getShortName returns not string but null, or smth else. You could try cast to string:
return (string) $this->getShortName();